# Passing Picklist Values to Controller with InputField in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, controller, picklist, inputfield

I'm new to VisualForce and trying to figure out how to pass the values a user selected from a birthday picklist into my controller. The picklists are fields of my Contact object and one is dependent on the other (the month selected determines the days selectable). Whenever I try to submit a value, nothing shows up (I have at least one contact for every birthday). How do I do this correctly?

Here is my VisualForce code:

```
<apex:page controller="BirthdayController">
    <apex:form >
        <h3>Enter Your Birthday:</h3>
        Month: <apex:inputField value="{!c.Month__c}"/>
        Day: <apex:inputField value="{!c.Day__c}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Birthdays">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Birthdays}" var="b">
                <apex:column value="{!b.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!b.LastName}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And here's my controller code:

```
public class BirthdayController
{
    public Contact c {get; set;}
    public String bday;
    public void submit()
    {
        bday = c.Month__c + '/' + c.Day__c;
    }
    public List<Contact> getBirthdays()
    {
        List<Contact> results = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Birthday__C = :bday];
        return results;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Basically what I'm trying to do is make it so that a user can select a date using the picklists and have all the contacts with matching birthdays show up. I know I could do this by manually creating a populating a selection list, but I want to use the contact fields because they are dependent. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `Contact` object whose fields your page sets, for example in your controller's constructor:

```
public BirthdayController() {
    c = new Contact();
}
```

Comment: That stopped the null issue but I guess I didn't explain what I'm trying to do. I want a user to be able to select a date from the picklist so that all contacts with their birthday as that date will be listed. So I'm not working with any one specific contact. Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: @user25888 The pattern you are using - using an object to present fields to use to filter other data - makes sense. The `getBirthdays` call in `submit` won't do anything because it will be the Visualforce referencing `getBirthdays` that will return the data. Not sure why you are not seeing results through.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that and realized that my problem was in how I defined my birthday field. I'm an idiot.